# Question regard almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need an example of an i.i.d. sequence of random variables $(X_i)$ such that

$$
X_1\cdot\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)\not\to X_1\mathbb{E}(X_1)
$$
almost surely as $n\to\infty$.

According to the law of large numbers the sum $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ converges almost surely to $\mathbb{E}(X_1)$, so, why should I care about $X_1$?

Comment: Hint: There is one more hypothesis of the SLLN and it's an important one.  You may want to look into Cauchy random variables and try to figure out why that's an example.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Do you mean an example in which $X_1$ "is not bounded"?

Comment: It's more than that.  You want an example where the first moment does not exist.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian So, given that the first moment is some constant, is the argument is true? what if $X_1$ is bounded?

Comment: If $X_i$ is a bounded $iid$ sequence, then $X_1 \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)$ converges almost surely to the random variable $X_1 E(X_1)$.

Comment: given that the first moment is some constant, is the argument is true?

How can the first moment not be a constant (if it exists)?

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian OK. Why it is not enough to demand that only $X_1$ be bounded (for a sequence of i.i.d. integrable random variables with the same first moment)? BTW, is there a weaker condition for convergence?

Comment: @Lost1 I meant exists, thanks!

Comment: It is enough to demand that $X_1$ be bounded since they are $iid$.  As you say, all the random variables are the same.  The weaker assumption needed is that the first moment exists.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian I see. How can I prove the last statement (using only the assumption of existence of the first moment) neatly?